# List contents of large tar archive quickly

Tags: linux, tar, archiving

I need to list the contents of a fairly large (gzipped) tar archive (about 37GiB). `tar -ztvf archive` takes forever. Is there some way to get this listing quickly? Possibly by only listing contents down to a certain directory depth?

Could I have done something while packing the archive to enable quicker listing of the contents?

Comment: I think next time I archive large chunks of files, I am going to try [dar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dar_%28disk_archiver%29) instead.

Answer (score 2):

So, you have a set of files, that you have made an archive using *"tar"*, which will create one output file. Then, you used *"gzip"* to compress that one *".tar"* file into a *".zip"*.

If that's the case, then the process of getting a listing of all the files in the *".tar"* file, requires that the *".tar"* file must be fully **unzipped** from the *".zip"* file, before the contents of the *".tar"* file can be listed.

This will always take more time than getting a listing of the files that are stored "directly" in a *".zip"* file. If the file is large, this time can be considerable.

If you want to reduce the time required to list the files in a compressed archive file, then:

1. **unzip** (uncompress) the *".tar"* file from the *".zip"* file, and expand the resulting *".tar"* file into the underlying fileset
2. create a *".zip"* file directly from the set of files.

This way, the files in the archive file can be listed without uncompressing the archive.

Answer (score 2):

`-z` means to `ungzip` or `gzip` the tar file. Tar itself bundles without compression. When you gzip there isn't much you can do, the metadata is in the tar file which is compressed,

```
$ gunzip -l co.tar.gz 
         compressed        uncompressed  ratio uncompressed_name
             177183             1044480  83.0% file.tar
```

That's all gzip sees. You've got to gunzip to get back to the tar.
The Unix way to get around this is simply to either generate a manifest, `find . > MANIFEST` and ship with that. However there are other options like rather than using `.tar.gz` simply ship out a different format that does not compress metadata. I think `7zip` fits that description.

More recently, people have taken to using `sha1sum` or `md5sum` which is a better plan than a regular MANIFEST.

```
find destination/ -type f -exec sha1sum {} +; > sha1sum
```

This can also be checked rather easily but is unnecessary because *both* tar and gzip provide checksums internally,

```
sha1sum -c ./sha1sum
```